# What kinds of questions are allowed on this site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette

I am pretty new to forums and Q&A sites. I also have a whitelisted browser with very few sites for learning about C# and [Windows Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms). What kinds of questions are allowed on this site? Do they have to be questions that have never been asked anywhere on the Internet? What kinds of questions are acceptable on SO?

For example, would I get negative responses for posting a question like, "How can I send create an SQL database and then pull from it in my C# application" even if others have asked this question on other sites?

I don't want to upset the community, so I want to make sure I know what kinds of questions I should ask.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help All kinds of info in that link.

Comment: The [tour] you read 2 days ago also had a lot of answers to this. You can always re-read it if you've forgotten what it said.

Comment: Good that you asked by the way. when in doubt ask on meta, no matter what happens in response to that meta post. But meta also holds a lot of answers already. Pretty much weekly there are several posts about question bans, closed questions, downvotes - those are good posts to read to get an idea of what not to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A question doesn't need to *not* exist somewhere else on the Internet; it just needs to not exist here on SO.

Your sample question, *"How can I send create an SQL database and then pull from it in my C# application"*, is too broad, too high level, it involves potentially installing a SQL server, configuring it, securing it, networking to allow the C# application access to it, access controls, and this is all before the SQL content required to do what you're wanting to do, and [SQL injection](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom) prevention, processing the result, etc. Questions on SO need to be about specific problems/tasks.